# Input of textField in TableViewCell disappeared after scrolling

Tags: swift

I have a UITableView with 12 cells. In the cells there is an UITextField. When I write something into the textfield and scroll down the input is moved to another cell or is removed.

Comment: Could you please put your update in an answer and accept the answer so that the question is no longer open? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

I've solved it on my own.

First I created a string array and put tags to the textfields in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" delegate. Then every time the player finished the editing of the text I save it to the string array.

```
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    let currentTag = textField.tag
    self.playerNamedFinishedEdit[currentTag] = textField.text!
}
```

In the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" i added the following code and all works fine now.

```
    cell.playerTextField.text = self.playerNamedFinishedEdit[indexPath.row]
```